# Interesting overlapping UIScrollView conundrum

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch, logic

Say you have two scrollviews, one vertical and one horizontal, that intersect in a "plus sign" pattern. Say you have one object (a UIImageView for example) in the center of the plus. If you touch the object and scroll upward, you want the object to scroll upward in the vertical scrollview. But if you touch the object and scroll sideways, you want it to scroll within the horizontal scrollview.

Problems:

1. Which scrollview is the object initially in? Or is it in neither? You don't know which scrollview the object is in until you detect which scrollview began scrolling.
2. If the vertical scrollview is on top, the horizontal scrollview would not receive touches in the center area where the scrollviews overlap.

Can anyone think of any solutions to this problem? (Change the design is not a solution)

Another way to think about it is this: You have a 100x100 grid of tiles, but you can only see a 10x10 grid on the screen at once. You want to be able to scroll each row sideways, but you also want to be able to scroll each column vertically. Obviously the scroll position would have to lock to the nearest multiple of tile size before each new touch/scroll began. But it means that at any given time any tile could be in either a horizontal or vertical scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Use a (single) scroll view (with `directionLockEnabled = YES`) for its physics, but don't actually make it the superview of your tiles.

See the WWDC2012 video "Enhancing User Experience with Scroll Views" for more on this technique.